# SSL certificate for Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, https, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I want to create a HTTPS Ingress for my microservice infrastructe, on Google Kubernetes Engine, for my **test** environment. Basic HTTP Ingress works fine and now I want to create a secure one. I don't have a domain, I want my UI to make requests via https directly on the Ingress IP.

I've used Let's Encrypt (sslforfree website) to create a certificate for an IP that was accessible to me. But this ip i've used for the domain name in the certificate is not the IP on which the Ingress was created. Now all requests return 401 and I don't know why. First error the browser returns is the following:

```
Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for 35.241.60.223. The certificate is only valid for 35.228.159.214.
 
Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

This is the problem: if I want to create an Ingress, on GKE, on HTTPS, I need a certificate. But I can't have the certificate until I know the Ingress IP.

I don't have much experience in HTTPS and Ingress and I don't know what is the easiest way for me to have a HTTP Ingress, in my test environment, without having any domain name.

Edit: I've created a domain comanddev.tk and forwarded that to ingress url location. I've created a certificate for comanddev.tk and updated ingress to use that certificate. Now the request is getting ERR_TIMEDOUT and I don't see anything in the Ingress Controller logs of use except `GET https://35.241.60.223/customer-service/actuator/health 401`

Comment: As you are using GKE, you want to use `GCP Ingress` or `Nginx Ingress`? Would this solution work for you [Using Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs). You could reserve global IP address.

Comment: I am using GKE, and I want a GCP Ingress

Comment: Your original question was how to create SSL certificate and it was answered. This second question should be created separately as its different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of my knowledge you cannot use Let's Encrypt for a certificate for only an IP address. You need a domain name as the certificate is used to "proof" you ownership or control over this domain.
See https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificate-for-public-ip-without-domain-name/6082/14
Your options would be to use self signed SSL certificates or register some kind of cheap (sub)domain for testing purposes which you can then point to the ingress IP.

Comment: So I get a domain, create a certificate for that domain. After that I create the ingress with that certificate, redirect URL from domain to ingress url and this should work?

Comment: It depends how you create your certificates and ingresses. Where do you get the letsencrypt certificate? Do you use the cert-manager within kubernetes? then have a look at the other answer, the ingress has to be configured to use letsencrypt. But in order for this to work your Domain Name must already point to the Ingress IP. Otherwise it depends what ingress you use and how you can insert your certificate to your ingress. Usually via Kubernetes Secrets or similar.

Comment: I did that and the request https://comanddev.tk/business-owner-service/actuator/health returns SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

Comment: This response is only on Firefox, on Chrome I get ERR_TIMED_OUT

Answer (score 1):

This is happening probably due to the ClusterIssuer/Issuer + Ingress config you have.
Please follow the follloing steps to have the right config:

```
   apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
   kind: Issuer
   metadata:
     name: letsencrypt-prod
   spec:
     acme:
       # The ACME server URL
       server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
       # Email address used for ACME registration
       email: user@example.com
       # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
       privateKeySecretRef:
         name: letsencrypt-prod
       # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
       solvers:
       - http01:
           ingress:
             class: nginx
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kuard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"    
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.example.com (you probably have an DNS default)
    secretName: quickstart-example-tls
  rules:
  - host: example.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: kuard
          servicePort: 80
```

Source:
https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/release-0.11/tutorials/acme/quick-start/index.html?highlight=lets#step-6-configure-let-s-encrypt-issuer

Comment: I am using my own containers (that are basically SpringBoot apps). What ingress.class is this? I don't think it's nginx

Answer (score 0):

Going back to the original question. If you are just testing, you don't necessarily have to get a DNS server to be able to get a cert from LetsEncrypt. You can use services like `nip.io` or `xip.io` which convert you IP addresses to DNS names and resolve without any setup. You could use https01 challenge to resolve with LetsEncrypt. `cert-manager` would simplify that setup for you.

`ERR_TIMEDOUT` would most probably be a networking issue. You will get some response from ingress controller if you are hitting it. Make sure your ingress controller is up and running, if it is then looking into networking devices in front of the cluster.

Refs:

1. https://nip.io/
2. https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/#installing-with-regular-manifests
3. https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/#step-6-configure-let-s-encrypt-issuer